# Force <TD> width IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I have a table where all columns need to be an exact minimum width.
If the table does not fit into it's container div the table will go into a scroll.
This is my setup:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td class='cell'>1</td>
      <td class='cell'>2</td>
   </tr>
</table>

.cell {
   width: 10em;
   min-width: 10em;
}
```

This works in every browser but `IE7` because `min-width` is not supported, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: No, but I can use normal javascript

Comment: Ah i found a css hack? Maybe try this

http://perishablepress.com/css-hackz-series-minimum-width-maximum-width-for-internet-explorer-6/

Comment: I do know that you should be using Double Quotes for the TD Class. No single quotes.

Comment: Try to set the table to have a width instead of just the cell.

Comment: @AaronBrewer single quotes are just as good. Where do you get your information? Tell them they're wrong.

Comment: @MrLister: I just know it is better practice, because I know computer generated HTML may use single quotes, when hand-written may use double quotes. I double quote everything to remain consistent, and in which what I was taught. I never said it was incorrect, I just think it's a better practice, to remain consistency. Same goes for my programming.

Comment: And also, this is from W3: "By default, SGML requires that all attribute values be delimited using either double quotation marks (ASCII decimal 34) or single quotation marks (ASCII decimal 39). Single quote marks can be included within the attribute value when the value is delimited by double quote marks, and vice versa. Authors may also use numeric character references to represent double quotes (&#34;) and single quotes (&#39;). For double quotes authors can also use the character entity reference &quot;." http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html

Comment: @AaronBrewer No, it isn't better practice. One is not better than the other. The link you quote doesn't favour one type of quote over the other either. Of course consistency is good, but the example in the question had nothing but single quotes, so it was consistent enough.

Comment: @AaronBrewer using width for the table is not an option, also the quotes are just an example.

Answer (score 0):

check this:

http://blog.throbs.net/2006/11/17/IE7+And+MinWidth+.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Its easier than you think:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td width=60>1</td>
      <td width=80>2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V8jny/

Answer (score -2):

```
#div {
    width:XXXpx; // the static width u want
    height:XXXpx; // the same with the height
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

hope, thats what u're looking for.

g.r.